# How to find out what powershell script is creating so much memory consumption?

Tags: powershell

There's a powershell script that's running on my server consuming 99% of the 32GBs of memory that I have. Is there something I can use to identify what script it is and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a Powershell prompt as administrator and run these two lines:

```
$id = (Get-Process powershell | sort WorkingSet -Descending | select -first 1).Id
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '$id'" | Select CommandLine
```

That will get the command line for the busiest powershell process. You need to run it as administrator or the command line will be empty.

Edit: You can use this one-liner to get the  busiest three processes' command lines:

```
Get-Process powershell | sort WorkingSet -Descending | Select -First 3 | %{Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($_.Id)" | Select CommandLine}
```

Comment: This will (likely) work, though it assumes that the process consuming the most processor time is also the one consuming the most memory.  Since memory usage is the issue it seems like querying one of the memory-related properties of the `Win32_Process` class, such as `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Property CommandLine, ProcessId, WorkingSetSize -Filter 'Name = ''powershell.exe''' | Sort-Object -Property WorkingSetSize -Descending | ...`, would be a more direct and reliable approach.

Comment: Good catch. Corrected to make it use WorkingSet instead of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

From an Administrative PowerShell prompt, first get all the PowerShell processes:

```
Get-Process PowerShell
```

Identify the one that is causing trouble, and get the Process ID. Now use WMI to get the command line that launched it:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "processid = '1234'" | Select Commandline
```

That should give you a starting point to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
get-process | sort ws
```